# Change SQL query dynamically in MyBatis

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I want to change the behavior of SQL queries based on some criteria.
For example, I want to "inject" "LIMIT 10" for every SELECT queries which select data from certain tables.
Or I might want to "inject" some kind of condition to every UPDATE statements.
Can I do that in MyBatis using Interceptor (@Intercepts)?